# Which one is better getOrDefault() or putIfAbsent() of HashMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

If I have to set values for a key (for many keys) in HashMap if not present then which one is better to use. 
**getOrDefault() or putIfAbsent()**
As both the method will return the value associated with the key if it is already set.
And both will take key,value pair as parameter.

Comment: Reading the doc would have give you the answer

Comment: Trying it could have given you the answer too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, they will both return the value associated with the key if it is already set, but one is only a getter while the other one is a setter.

**putIfAbsent**

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is
>   mapped to null) associates it with the given value and returns null,
>   else returns the current value.

---

**getOrDefault**

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or
>   defaultValue if this map contains no mapping for the key.

---

If your goal is only to retrieve the value, then use `getOrDefault`. Else, if you want to set the value when it does not exist, use `putIfAbsent`.

According to your first sentence,

> If I have to set values for a key (for many keys) in HashMap if not
>   present then which one is better

you should use `putIfAbsent`.

Answer (score 21):

In Java8 There is also `computeIfAbsent` which returns the value if present or if it is absent it creates it through a lambda function, adds it to the `Map` and returns its value.

```
Value v = map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Value(f(k)));
```

Comment: So, basically, `computeIfAbsent` is like a `getOrPutDefaultAndGet` ?

Comment: @Kathir, yes! Although because the computation of the default is a lambda it is only invoked if the key is absent so there is no danger that the computation of the default will be invoked unless really needed.

Answer (score 13):

`getOrDefault()` doesn't mutate the map, so you won't find the values in the map if you subsequently inspected its contents, e.g.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.getOrDefault("something", "default");  // returns "default"
assertTrue(map.isEmpty());
```

`putIfAbsent()` does mutate the map, so you would find the values in the map if you subsequently inspected its contents, e.g.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.putIfAbsent("something", "default");
assertFalse(map.isEmpty());
```

You should pick the one appropriate to your needs.